# Sql Server DateDiff in minutes is different than C#'s TotalMinutes

Tags: c#, sql-server

In Sql Server if I run this:

```
Select DateDiff(mi,'2019-09-16 10:26:33.000', '2019-09-16 10:33:01.000')
```

I get 7

But in C#:

```
DateTime endTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-09-16 10:33:01.000");
DateTime startTime = DateTime.Parse("2019-09-16 10:26:33.000");

int minutes = (int)(endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes;
```

This returns 6. How can I get synchronized output in both cases? I want my C# code to return the same as my SQL Server - not just in this case but in all cases regardless of date times used.

Comment: `How can I get synchronized output in both cases?` Create a new date with just the year, month, day, hour and minute. Then subtract those. Or `Math.Ceiling` rather than cast to int.

Comment: In SQL you are rounding to minutes with 'mi', and in c# you are not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using this Linq method instead:

```
int minutes = System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.DateDiffMinute(startTime, endTime);
```

Comment: FYI this also covers Month/Day/Year/Hours/Seconds/Miliseconds

Answer (score 0):

The expressions aren't similar. The first expression you are getting the number of minutes between the 2 datetimes, which is calculated by the number of "ticks". In this case you have 26 and 33 minutes, so the minute value has "ticked" 7 times (`33-26=7`).

For the other expression you are subtracting the later value from the earlier and then getting the number of minutes in that value. *If* C# starts it's clock at the same time as SQL Server, this would result in the time `1900-01-01 00:06:28.000`; hence why you have 6.

If you want the latter answer in T-SQL, then you would do something like this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(MINUTE,CONVERT(datetime,'2019-09-16T10:33:01.000') - CONVERT(datetime,'2019-09-16T10:26:33.000'));
```

Comment: I'd really like to hear what the downvote is for; how can this answer be improved on and what is "wrong" about it?

Answer (score 0):

You truncate the result of `(endTime - startTime).TotalMinutes` by casting it to an `int`, which rounds it down to 6. The actual result of this statement is probably slightly less then 7 (for instance 6.999999997). By casting it to an `int` you truncate it (cutting off after the comma) which results in 6 and not 7.